# Modal Popups in Delphi Firemonkey on Android

Tags: android, delphi, modal-dialog, popup

I am working on an Android Application, but I need a Popup, which I can call in code to create a Modal Popup, so set a Variable in Code.
I tried to spread it around different functions, and it worked, but its getting quite bad to follow the code, when jumping from one Funktion to another...

What I want to do is like the function `MessageDlg()`, but it is not implemented on Android.

I've tried the `MessageDlg()` with the Anonymous Function, but that also runs the code underneath befor i press a button.

I need something like that, but on Android the if statement will be executed befor i entered my input.

```
MyInt: Integer;
begin

  MessageDlg('You want to Continue?', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
  [System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], 0,
  procedure(const AResult: TModalResult) begin
    case AResult of
      mrYes:
        MyInt := 0;
      mrNo:
        MyInt := 1;
    end;
  end);

  if MyInt = 0 then
    //Do Something
  else
    //Do Something
end;
```

I need it for something like "Click a button to Continue event"

Comment: You might want to make the user think that the messagedlg is modal, when it actually isn't (but they don't know that). To do this, show a panel that covers the entire screen in a transparent shade of grey (and with it's HitTest=True) before you use the code that @Dalija Prasnikar shows below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to move your logic into anonymous method. That will be executed after user clicks appropriate button. You also don't need `MyInt` variable in that case.

```
begin

  MessageDlg('You want to Continue?', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
  [System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], 0,
  procedure(const AResult: TModalResult) begin
    case AResult of
      mrYes:
        begin
          //Do Something (MyInt = 0 branch)
        end;
      mrNo:
        begin
          //Do Something (MyInt = 1 branch)
        end;
    end;
  end);

end;
```